# Errors while running Artisan in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Whenever i try to run any `php artisan` commands from the command line, I get the following error(s):

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Call to a member function connection() on a non-object","file":"C:\\wamp
\\www\\cms\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Mod
el.php","line":2649}}{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\Fat
alErrorException","message":"Call to a member function connection() on a non-obj
ect","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\cms\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Da
tabase\\Eloquent\\Model.php","line":2649}}
```

I have specified the Laravel version as 4.1.* in my composer.json but since i can't run artisan, i don't know the exact version.

This problem didn't use to happen before. And the website seems to be running fine, despite of the errors occuring in `php artisan`. Composer commands also work fine, as far as i can tell.

Any ideas why it is happening now?

Comment: Have you run a Composer Update? This might be the issue. Also, if you are upgrading from 4.0 to 4.1 then you should follow this... http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade

Comment: already done that. still getting same errors.

Comment: Did you make any changes prior to this message? Maybe you should try backtracking a bit.

Any changes to this file maybe?
C:\\wamp
\\www\\cms\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php","line":2649

Comment: @SUB0DH: Check this [link](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=14766), this might help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error seems to have happened, because for the mail configuration in `app/config/mail.php`, I made it to retrieve the values from the database instead of specifying the configuration options directly in that file.

So, I had to check if the function for getting the value is called from the web or from the command line. If the function is called from the command line, I simply returned an empty string.

```
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    return '';
}
```